# Setting up ANT facing issues

Tags: deployment, package, ant

I'm trying to setup ANT in my system but it is not working well. I tried and reverified the variables and checked everything still it doesn't work. I even checked if the path is fine via CMD which are fine but doesn't work.
Give me suggestions on how to solve this.
TIA
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're trying to use Apache ANT here? That's a very old method of performing deployments. [Salesforce DX (shortened to sfdx), a.k.a the Salesforce CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm) is the current toolset. `sfdx force:source:deploy` accomplishes the same thing as ANT would (but without much of the headache of setting up tasks and storing credentials in plain text).

Comment: @DerekF I'm going to install Salesforce DX soon, I had a problem before and I'll try to fix from my side.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the CMD and ran the following

```
set PATH=%BASEPATH%
set ANT_HOME=C:\ANTHOME\apache-ant-1.10.12
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18
set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
```

I also changed the ANTHOME folder name to avoid confusion.